# SharePoint 2007: Formatting a FormField

Tags: sharepoint, date, formatting, formfield

I'm trying to display the page owner and last modified date on the footer of a SharePoint master page for a publishing site.  On my master page I currently have:

```
<SharePoint:FormattedString FormatText="Page owner: {0} Last updated: {1:dd/MM/yyyy}" runat="server">
<SharePoint:FormField ControlMode="Display" FieldName="PublishingContact" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>
<SharePoint:FormField ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Modified" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server" />
</SharePoint:FormattedString>
```

This works great, however it doesn't modify the date format:

> Page owner: litwareinc\treesj Last updated: 3/31/2009 10:32 PM

I'm guessing the date is returned as a string so the formatting of dd/MM/yyyy does nothing.  I realize modifying the regional settings on the web application might fix this however I'm more interested in how this could be implemeneted with a different format to the default.

Thanks in advance!

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the FormField control has already rendered the output as a string so wrapping it inside FormattedString won't work.

An alternative to [Nat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13813/nat)'s answer is to write your own control and wrap the FormFields within that. You can then capture the rendered output and transform as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to place a `<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField/>` See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.datetimefield.aspx).
But this is SharePoint so also see [here](http://sharepointers.blogspot.com/2008/09/publishing-page-layout-datetimefield.html) to add some code behind to render in a different format with a little code behind.