# Is it possible to format a NumberField in a page layout?

Tags: sharepoint, formatting, moss, page-layout

I'm developing a SharePoint publishing site and setting up its content types and page layouts. I need to display the value for a Year field with type Number. The markup currently is:

```
<SharePointWebControls:NumberField FieldName="Year" runat="server" id="Year" />
```

The problem with the default behaviour is that it shows each number with a comma, e.g. "2,009" instead of "2009". Is there a way I can set some sort of String.Format syntax on the field to make it display correctly?

I tried creating a new rendering template which looks like this:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="YearNumberField" runat="server">
  <Template>
    <SharePoint:FormField ID="TextField" runat="server"/>
  </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

... but there doesn't appear to be any 'Format' property on the FormField object.

Thanks for any help.

**Update:**

I tried wrapping the SharePoint:FormField tag inside SharePoint:FormattedString. Unfortunately the field was not formatted, same results as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704332/sharepoint-2007-formatting-a-formfield).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the rendering template must use FormField. This always renders the value in the format: **1,989&nbsp;**. To resolve this the rendered text needs to be trapped and altered to get the desired output. Here are two approaches to resolving this:

**1. Write a custom control inherited from NumberField**

The RenderFieldForDisplay and RenderFieldForInput methods can be overridden to provide the desired output. Additional properties can be added to the control to describe additional behaviour.

*Pros: No changes to rendering templates required.*

**2. Write a custom control for use in the rendering template**

A control that (for example) uses regular expressions to alter text can wrap around the FormField control.

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="YearField" runat="server">
    <Template>
        <RX:RegexManipulatorControl runat="server"
                Mode="Replace"
                Expression=","
                Replacement="">
            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server"/>
        </RX:RegexManipulatorControl>
    </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

*Pros: Generic solution can be used for any type of field.*

Answer (score -1):

from *Just Another SharePoint Blog*

> Open the list view in SharePoint
>   Designer.
>
> Right click on the data view web part.
>   (the list)
>
> Select Convert to XSLT Data View
>
> Click on the number field you would
>   like to format
>
> A > will appear showing Data Field,
>   Format As
>
> Click on the link below Format As -
>   Number formatting options
>
> Under Options deselect Use 1000
>   separator
>
> Click OK
>
> Save your changes and hit F12 to
>   preview

Comment: Thanks Steve but this is in a page layout, there are no web parts involved.